# Print id inside option

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this code where it works is to know how many people are booked for the day that I enter in the form.
The query works well and returns the expected result.
The problem is that I would like to show this result next to an hour of the select, so it doesn't show me.
If the div of the id result-date or pull out of the select of the different time options I see the result.
What could I do to see the result of the query within an option?

This is the file of check_availablity.php.

```
require('config.php');

sleep(1);

$data = $_POST['data'];

$result = $connexion->query(
    'SELECT persones FROM reservas where data = \''.$data.'\' ORDER by hora ASC'
);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    foreach ($result as $hores){
        echo $hores['persones'].' llocs disponibles.';
    }
}
else{
    echo 'Esta tot reservat';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rem la Ràpita</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../images/favicon.png" sizes="32x32"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!--Comprovar la disponibilitat d'horari-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $('#data').on('blur', function(){

                var data = $(this).val();       
                var dataString = 'data='+data;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "check_availablity.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#result-data').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                    }
                });
            });              
        });    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container-login">
            <div class="wrap-login" style="width: 1000px">
                <!--<form class="login-form validate-form" action="bd/reservar.php" method="post">-->
                <form class="login-form validate-form" action="bd/reservar.php" method="post">
                    <span class="login-form-title"></span>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="wrap-input100 col-xs-6 espai-davant-text" data-validate = "Nom incorrecte">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 col-xs-6 espai-davant-text" data-validate = "Email incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" placeholder="" >
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100" style="width:100%" data-validate = "Email incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 col-xs-6 espai-davant-text" data-validate="Telefon incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="text" id="telefon" name="telefon" placeholder="">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 col-xs-6 espai-davant-text" data-validate="Persones incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="number" id="persones" name="persones" placeholder="">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100" style="width:100%" data-validate="Data incorrecto">
                            <input class="input100" type="date" id="data" name="data" placeholder="Fecha">
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100" style="width:100%" data-validate="Hora incorrecto">
                            <select name="hora" id="hora" class="input100">
                                <option disabled selected></option>
                                <option value="12:00">12:00</option><div id="result-data"></div>   
                                <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
                                <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                                <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
                                <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                                <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
                                <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
                                <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
                                <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
                                <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
                                <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="focus-efecto"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-login-form-btn">
                            <div class="wrap-login-form-btn">
                                <div class="login-form-bgbtn"></div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="login-form-btn">RESERVAR</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I find this question difficult to understand due to the grammar problems.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: Your server-side script should not echo the data directly, but gather it in an array, using the actual hour value (in `HH:mm` format) as key, and the number of persons as value. Then you encode that as JSON, and pass it back to the client. There you loop over this data now, using the key to select the corresponding option (keyword: attribute selector), and then you set the option's text value, combining the time value, and the number of persons.

Comment: Since your query will only return data for already "booked" hours, you will also need to reset the text of the options first - otherwise, when you selected one day that got you `12:30 (4 llocs disponibles)`, showing in an option, and now you select a day that has no bookings for that time, the option would keep showing that text, because you will only be updating the ones for which you got data from the server.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much, for answering my question, because in the world of json I am very new, I just started now, could you help me with an example of the code?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use ajax to change the selected **option** ? That will not work. And a **div** tag on the option will not work either.

The **select** is normally styled by the OS and it is not easy to change things in it.  It makes no sense to use ajax to display something next to an option.

If your goal is to update the dropdown, before the user opens it, then use the ajax to replace the complete **select** element, including the options.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to do it?